# Where is Gmail Archive option in Evolution?

Tags: email, evolution, gmail

How can I easily archive my gmail account emails in Evolution? I would like a solution easily as gmail archive. After lot of googling the only solution that I found is manually sending to the All Email Folder :/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply click 'delete' to remove an email from the Inbox. [By default](https://askubuntu.com/a/57820/349837) the email will still be available in the *All Mail* folder. If you really want to delete an email (something you probably don't do as often as 'archive'), drag that email to the Google Mail trash folder.

Comment: That is true by default, but depends on how Gmail is configured, see dave's answer and the comment.

Comment: Testing this out in evolution doesn't work as expected - my settings match those above (by default), and 'Delete' in evolution moves it to my gmail trash folder

Answer (score 10):

Since October 2014, Evolution supports archiving. Archive action is available via the message menu (right-click on the message) and the default shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

From [this post](https://ttboj.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/testing-evolutions-git-master-and-gnome-continuous/):

> **Archive like Gmail does**
>
> If you use Evolution with a Gmail account, and you want the same functionality as the Gmail archive button, you can accomplish this by setting the Evolution archive folder to point to the Gmail “All Mail” folder, which will cause the Evolution archive action to behave as Gmail’s does.
>
> To use this functionality (with or without Gmail), simply select the messages you want to move, and click the “Archive…” button:
>
> This is also available via the “Message” menu. You can also activate with the Control-Alt-a shortcut.

Comment: I tested this and it works, but I recommend putting the most basic content here and link the post for reference

Comment: Not sure if that shortcut is correct for older versions, but evolution 3.26.1 has the keyboard shortcut set to Ctrl-Alt-A (not Shift)

Answer (score 7):

Had trouble setting this up until I found [this related question & answer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/71526/how-do-i-enable-the-archive-in-evolution/)

> Open *Evolution Preferences* under the Edit menu. Under *Mail Accounts* click once on the account in question and click the *Edit* button on the right. This will open the *Account Editor*. Click on *Defaults* and you should see there under *Special Folders* a setting for the *Archive Folder* which may be unset. Click the button to choose a folder to archive messages to. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> should archive an email.

For gmail, you'll want to use 'All Mail' as the 'Archive' folder.  You can do a similar thing with trash / spam - by default they map to the gmail trash/spam folders, but you can configure a folder to move them to.

Answer (score 5):

In the Settings on the Gmail website, you can set it to archive deleted messages so whenever you delete a message it will be archived on Gmail's server.

The settings can be found in Gmail -> Settings -> Forward and POP/IMAP with the label **When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder**. Here is a picture of the settings, it's the 3rd section.

[image: screenshot of the settings]

Comment: Yes, there is an option Gmail->Settings->Forward and POP/IMAP that reads: "When a message is marked as deleted and expunged from the last visible IMAP folder: [x] Archive the message (default)"

Comment: Testing this out in evolution doesn't work as expected - my settings match those above (by default), and 'Delete' in evolution moves it to my gmail trash folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you are having is related to the POP protocol.  You may want to check into IMAP:

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&ctx=mail&answer=75725

I don't know if IMAP, works as well as POP via Evolution, but I don't see a reason it shouldn't.  The main thing that you need to make clear is whether or not you want your Evolution archive to directly correlate to your gmail account.

Because at the end of the day an archive is just a database. (aka a folder containing old emails).   And beagle or other search plugins can give you the same exact functionality as the web based service.